# Highlighting the selected row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a table in a html.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <button onclick="someFunction()">
    </td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <button onclick="someFunction()">
    </td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <button onclick="someFunction()">
    </td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each row having a dynamic id ,Here is my question **I want highlight the current row of the table which button been pressed**.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: are closing `<button>` in your real code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good approach will be is to change your markup like

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td><button>click</button></td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button>click</button></td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button>click</button></td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
#mytable tr.highlight{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

then

```
$('#mytable button').click(function(){
    $('#mytable tr.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
    someFucntion();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/25p26zrj/)

Comment: This code is an approach that better responds to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest()` in jquery to select the parent `<tr>`.

### HTML

```
<tr><td><button onclick="someFucntion(this)"></td><td>data</td></tr>
```

### JS

```
function someFunction(elm){
 $("tr.highLightClass").removeClass("highLightClass");// remove class if it is having someone
$(elm).closest("tr").addClass("highLightClass"); // here selected row

}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/deqrjgen/)

If you want to use "best practice", remove all inline handlers. Try this:

```
$("button.someClass").click(function () {
    $("tr.highLightClass").removeClass("highLightClass"); // remove class if it is having someone
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("highLightClass"); // here selected row

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/deqrjgen/1/)

Comment: also in addition to the code above style the added class via css

Comment: @RahulPatil sorry i misunderstand send msg  to you ,anyway thanks for ur comment

Comment: @Downvoters  care to comment for your down vote cast

Answer (score 0):

Onclick is outdated and is a very bad practice.. Add a class / id to selector..

```
<table>
<tr><td><button class="clickMe"></td><td>data</td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('body').on("click", ".clickMe", function(){
    var that = this;
    that.closest("tr").addClass("highlightMe");
});
```

Why use on?

If your table is being generated dynamically or rows are being added on the go, you should watch the new dynamic elements as well..

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand the following: when you click the button inside the  you want the corresponding `<tr>` to be highlighted.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/WBison/2vkfn5uy/2/

Basically, use the event object to retrieve the target node (the button), then the parent of that (the `<td>`), then the parent of THAT (the `<tr>`). Then just use any method you'd like to change the style.

Code:

Button function call: `<button onclick="someFunction(event)">`

```
function someFunction(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Hope this helps.